# Proof in Agda and how to evaluate list based function in C-c C-n

Tags: agda

I am new in Agda

BTW, how could i evaluate a list related function like reverse by C-c C-n ?

I mean how could i type the list like reverse [1,2,3] as in Haskell but it not work in agda.

Many thanks

Comment: Please don't edit the original question out. Now a big part of @Vitus's answer doesn't make sense unless someone reviews the history of your question. Part of the appeal of the SO sites is that answers are valuable for posterity, so editing out the key parts of a question goes against the spirit of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"For any" is universal quantification, which translates into dependent function types. As an example, let's take the following theorem: For any natural number *n* greater than zero, there exists a natural number *m*, such that S(*m*) = *n*.

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Product
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

theorem : (n : ℕ) → 0 < n → Σ[ m ∈ ℕ ] (suc m ≡ n)
theorem zero    ()
theorem (suc n) _  = n , refl
```

We can rewrite your theorem using the same pattern:

```
theorem : {A B : Set} (f : A → B) {m n : ℕ} →
  A has-size m → B has-size n → n < m →
  Σ[ a ∈ A ] Σ[ a′ ∈ A ] (a ≢ a′ → f a ≡ f a′)
```

This is a bit more involved: for any sets `A` and `B`, any function `f` from `A` to `B` and any natural numbers `m` and `n` such that `A` has `m` and `B` has `n` elements and `m` is greater than `n`, there exist elements `a` and `a′` in `A` such that even if `a` is different from `a′`, `f a` is equal to `f a′`. Note that I cut the `b` element; it's still the same theorem but a bit easier to write down.

`_has-size_` remains to be defined. I suggest defining `A has-size m` to be the statement that `A` is isomorphic to `Fin m` (`Fin` can be found in `Data.Fin`). If your assumptions are that `A` is isomorphic to `Fin m` and `B` to `Fin n`, you can do the proof on numbers (which is far easier) and then transform those numbers back to elements of `A` or `B`.

---

As for your second question:

```
C-c C-n reverse (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ [])
```

gives back

```
3 ∷ 2 ∷ 1 ∷ []
```

You might have tried to write the list as `[1, 2, 3]` as you would in Haskell, but this shortcut is not present in Agda. With clever use of operators, you could probably make it sort of work, though it would certainly require more whitespace (such as `[ 1 , 2 , 3 ]`), but I don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot, u exactly fix my problems. Can u explain more about your suggestion that [A has-size m to be the statement that A is isomorphic to Fin m]  i want to delate a function _has-size_  but the second argument is my goal, can u explain me how to define A is isomorphic to Fin m, since i know the defition of Fin. Tanks so much !

Comment: @user3582269: Take a look at the definition of `_≃_` in https://gist.github.com/vituscze/8633260#file-incompatibility-agda-L14

Comment: thanks for your patience，  but i am wondering the type of the function _has-size_    is?

Comment: @user3582269: Something like `Set → ℕ → Set`.

Comment: may i just let {A : Fin m}{B : Fin n} instead of the satament has-size?

Comment: @user3582269: If you want to go that way, you'd just skip specifying `A` and `B` completly and just replace them with `Fin m` and `Fin n`.